# How can I collect info to a txt file and print to terminal?

Tags: julia

How can I collect info to a txt file and print to terminal? I need it to output to txt file and to terminal[image]

Comment: Please remove the image and add the code you have as (properly formatted) text.

Comment: Also look at Suppressor.jl (and, more generally, `redirect_stdout`/`redirect_stderr`).

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Logging module](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/):

```
# Load the logging module
using Logging

# Open a textfile for writing
io = open("log.txt", "w+")

# Create a simple logger
logger = SimpleLogger(io)

# Log a task-specific message
with_logger(logger) do
    @info("a context specific log message")
end

# Write all buffered messages to the file
flush(io)

# Set the global logger to logger
global_logger(logger)

# This message will now also be written to the file
@info("a global log message")

# Close the file
close(io)
```